# Eclipse cant start jboss as7.1, working from command line

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

I have problem to start jboss from eclipse, however i have no problem to start by doing ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=yourserverip -Djboss.bind.address.management=yourserverip& from command line. it is already set to jdk7 in eclipse. does it look like a permission issue? how can we solve it? 
the exception in eclipse is

```
Unable to set property fileName on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(PropertyConfigurator.java:187)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyConfigurator.java:312)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:86)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:285)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:283)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:266)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:252)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1136)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1133)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:198)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:175)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/log/boot.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:152)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:183)
    ... 21 more
21:45:57,441 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
21:45:57,747 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
21:45:57,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
21:45:57,836 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.as: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014922: Directory /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/data/content is not writable
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.<init>(ContentRepository.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory.addService(ContentRepository.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService.start(ApplicationServerService.java:134) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more

21:45:57,841 ERROR [stderr] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
21:45:57,841 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)
21:45:57,841 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)
21:45:57,841 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:98)
21:45:57,841 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
21:45:57,842 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
21:45:57,842 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
21:45:57,842 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
21:45:57,842 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
21:45:57,842 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
21:45:57,843 ERROR [stderr] Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as: Failed to start service
21:45:57,843 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767)
21:45:57,843 ERROR [stderr]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
21:45:57,844 ERROR [stderr]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
21:45:57,844 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
21:45:57,844 ERROR [stderr] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014922: Directory /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/data/content is not writable
21:45:57,845 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.<init>(ContentRepository.java:123)
21:45:57,845 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory.addService(ContentRepository.java:97)
21:45:57,845 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService.start(ApplicationServerService.java:134)
21:45:57,845 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
21:45:57,846 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
21:45:57,846 ERROR [stderr]     ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file in question is `/usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/log/boot.log`.  The user you're using probably needs read and write on it.  If you're the owner of the file, `chmod 755 /usr/local/share/jboss/standalone/log/boot.log` should fix it up.

Comment: yes, i just found the problem too. when i install jboss, it is under a new user appuser. while my root user name is admin. when ealier i check the permission for jboss folder, i only check permission for /jboss which admin and appuser both have permission, but i forgot to check one more level further. so when eclipse start jboss which is under admin, i got the problem.