# Deploying with JBoss 7.1.1.Final on Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I've installed `JBoss-as-7.1.1.Final` on `Mac OSX Mountain Lion` and it seems to be on working order since I can access the management console on `localhost 9990`.  Unfortunately, any decent tutorials for `OSX` I've come across end at exactly this point.  I have no idea how to deploy a file.

I have `Eclipse Kepler` set up with `JBoss` tools installed, and that seems to have worked without a hitch. The Eclipse GUI has been changed appropriately.

I have a `JBoss` project in my workspace which is working on everyone else's (Windows) `JBoss` configuration, but when I try run as>run on server, here are the first few lines printed to the console:

```
Unable to set property fileName on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(PropertyConfigurator.java:187)
at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyConfigurator.java:312)
at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:128)
at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:86)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:264)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:262)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:262)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:245)
at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:225)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1295)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1293)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:176)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:153)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/dannyflynn/Desktop/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:152)
at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:183)
... 22 more
```

I've also tried running on J2EE preview server, which is normally met with: "Server JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server failed to start."

The screen at localhost 8080 remains unchanged in all cases.  However, this was not happening yesterday.  At least yesterday it changed to a blank screen indicating that it could not access the server whenever I tried to run the program.  I'm not sure what has changed since.

Tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720150/eclipse-cant-start-jboss-as7-1-working-from-command-line) of using chmod 755 on standalone/boot.log.  It produces the following output to the terminal:

```
chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...
```

The console output seems to be more or less the same, still beginning with a complaint about being unable to set property filename, but now there's a pop-up window stating "Server JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server failed to start."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse cant start jboss as7.1, working from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720150/eclipse-cant-start-jboss-as7-1-working-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't managed to fix this using the permissions approach directly.  This may have more to do with my lack of understanding of it than anything else.  However, what did work for me was the following.

1. Re-install JBoss
2. Create another management domain user ( I didn't do anything different here as far as I know, though going by the SO consensus, this is probably where the problem lay)
3. Place the mySQL connector back in JBOSSHOME/standalone/deployments and recreate the dependency for it through the JBOSS management console.
4. Run Mvn clean install on the project
5. Maven>Update project through Eclipse.
6. Export project as war file to JBOSSHOME/standalone/deployments
7. Run standalone.sh

Everything is now running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear it's a permissions issue with the `boot.log` file. Check that your user as sufficient permissions to write to the directory and/or file.